# How to specify font size in nifty GUI when using ttf fonts

Tags: jmonkeyengine, nifty-gui

I'm trying to use a font with a larger size in a ttf file using nifty GUI. All questions and answers I've seen are concerned with making fonts in fnt fonts in a different size, but the size I want to use is actually included in the ttf file. I tried setting `fontSize` and `size` attributes with no effect (no errors but the font size does not change either)

Below is the xml excerpt where I'm trying to use the ttf font with a large size:

```
<control id="score"
name="label"
color="#fff"
text="0"
width="50%"
height="20%"
textHAlign="left"
font="Interface/Fonts/Kenney Future.ttf"/>
```